# Azure CosmosDB (Mongo/Mongoose) deleteMany() fails if partioned

Tags: mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to do a deleteMany({}) to remove all the documents in a collection. If I do not have a partition key on the collection, this works. If I have a key (in the case /city) then I get an error.

```
query in command must target a single shard key"
code:61
```

How can I clear the full collection, it is too hard to specify every single city where the users live!, and Cosmos is asking for a partition key when I use the Portal (or emulator) to create the collection). I can get no partition key only by doing the mongoose insertMany() when there is no prior collection.

Code snippet: (the error comes on the deleteMany({})

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    addressNumber: Number,
    streetName: String,
    city: String,
    email: String
})

        this.users = mongoose.model('person', personSchema)

        try {
            await this.users.deleteMany({})
        } catch (err) {
            this.log.error(`cannot empty collection: ${err}`)
        }
```

Comment: can you simply drop the collection instead of deleting docs?

Comment: I was getting errors that way also. Can you tell me the correct way do do that?

Comment: Looking at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/34813063-cosmosdb-mongo-api-delete-many-with-partition-ke it seems this issue was addressed about 1 month ago.  Perhaps your version needs updating?

Comment: I just created the DB three days ago. I can't see where you check the version, and there does not seem to be a way to upgrade if it is the old API. I know the emulator is certainly stuck at the older version for now.